# When to malloc for structures and "create" functions in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, malloc

Consider a struct, let's say List, and a function to return a new List called ListCreate().   ListCreate() takes an object pointer as a parameter, which is an attribute for a List.

Now as far as my understanding goes, allocating heap memory should be handled by the caller.

Originally, my ListCreate() allocated memory for the new List object that was to be returned, and returned a pointer to that List object.  This didn't seem to cause any problems, but I realize now it makes sense to have the caller take care of that.

What confuses me though, is that if I create a List object like so:

```
List* ListCreate(*foo fum) {
    struct List ls;
    ls.foo = fum;
    ls.data = 0;

    return &ls;
}
```

...then the attributes for List (ls.foo) only exist locally for this function.  So when I return &ls back to a List pointer in main() that allocated its own memory for a List object, my understanding is that ls.foo, ls.data (and whatever other potential attributes) and &ls are no longer meaningful

One possible solution I'm thinking of is to have ListCreate() also allocate memory for a List object's attributes on the heap, and then have its complementary ListDestroy() function handle freeing that memory, but then I assume that means all of a List object's attributes should actually be pointers with space allocated for whatever they point to.

I don't know if that is necessarily conventional -- if my understanding is correct, how is this case typically handled?

Comment: I've seen the dynamic allocation in a Create/Destroy context you have mentioned in cases where the implementation of the struct is not known to the caller -- forward declarations, for example, where the caller would be unable to instantiate an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always create parallel `create` and `destroy` functions (even if `destroy` is just a call to `free`), and generally avoid functions that access its members directly (make it opaque if possible).

```
List *ListCreate(Foo *arg) { List *rv = calloc(1, sizeof(List)); rv.arg = arg; return rv; }
void ListDestroy(List *lst) { free(lst); }
```

Answer (score 0):

What solution you suggested is the conventional way. 
In the caller function do:

```
struct List ls;
```

Then in the called function:

```
int ListCreate(*foo fum, struct List *ls) {

    ls->foo = fum;
    ls->data = 0;

    return 0;
}
```